# Remote access to an Azure Postgres database

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I'm having trouble connecting to an Azure PostgreSQL database (or "Azure Database for PostgreSQL server" as they call it).

I can connect to it using psql from a VM inside Azure. It looks like this:

```
psql --user=UUU --host=HHH DB
Password for user UUU:

psql (10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
```

But when I try exactly the same command from my home machine, it fails:

```
psql --user=UUU --host=HHH DB

psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

On the Azure database's *Connection Security* blade, I have

- added a firewall rule with start IP=0.0.0.0 and end IP=255.255.255.255
- set "enforce SSL connection" to disabled
- turned on "allow access to Azure services".

I can't think of anything else to try. Any suggestions?

My home machine is running Windows+WSL, and I'm trying to connect from WSL / Ubuntu 18.04. My home machine has psql version 11.6. The database is running PostgreSQL 10.

Answer (score 0):

Azure seems to rely on multi-tenant Postgres which requires the hostname as part of the user string to handle connections. Try with a user: `user@my-db-subdomain`.